# Accessing a C/C++ structure of callbacks through a DLL's exported function using JNA

Tags: dll, callback, jna

I have a vendor supplied .DLL and an online API that I am using to interact with a piece of radio hardware; I am using JNA to access the exported functions through Java (because I don't know C/C++).  I can call basic methods and use some API structures successfully, but I am having trouble with the callback structure.  I've followed the TutorTutor guide [here](http://tutortutor.ca/cgi-bin/makepage.cgi?/articles/rjna) and also tried Mr. Wall's authoritative guide [here](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/CallbacksAndClosures.md), but I haven't been able to formulate the Java side syntax for callbacks set in a structure correctly.

I need to use this **exported function**:

```
BOOL __stdcall SetCallbacks(INT32 hDevice,
                            CONST G39DDC_CALLBACKS *Callbacks, DWORD_PTR UserData);
```

This function references the **C/C++ Structure**:

```
typedef struct{
    G39DDC_IF_CALLBACK               IFCallback;
    //more omitted
} G39DDC_CALLBACKS;
```

...which according to the API has these Members (*Note this is not an exported function*):

```
VOID __stdcall IFCallback(CONST SHORT *Buffer, UINT32 NumberOfSamples,
                          UINT32 CenterFrequency, WORD Amplitude,
                          UINT32 ADCSampleRate, DWORD_PTR UserData);
//more omitted
```

I have a G39DDCAPI.java where I have loaded the DLL library and reproduced the API exported functions in Java, with the help of JNA.  Simple calls to that work well.

I also have a G39DDC_CALLBACKS.java where I have implemented the above C/C++ structure in a format works for other API structures.  This callback structure is where I am unsure of the syntax:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD.DWORD_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback;

public class G39DDC_CALLBACKS extends Structure {
    public G39DDC_IF_CALLBACK               IFCallback;
    //more omitted

    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[] {
            "IFCallback","DDC1StreamCallback" //more omitted
        });
    }

    public static interface G39DDC_IF_CALLBACK extends StdCallCallback{
         public void invoke(ShortBuffer _Buffer,int NumberOfSamples,
                            int CenterFrequency, short  Amplitude,
                            int ADCSampleRate, DWORD_PTR UserData);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**  I made my arguments more type safe as Technomage suggested.  I am still getting a null pointer exception with several attempts to call the callback. Since I'm not sure of my syntax regarding the callback structure above, I can't pinpoint my problem in the main below.  Right now the relevant section looks like this:

```
int NumberOfSamples=65536;//This is usually 65536.
ShortBuffer _Buffer = ShortBuffer.allocate(NumberOfSamples);
int CenterFrequency=10000000;//Specifies center frequency (in Hz) of the useful band
                             //in received 50 MHz wide snapshot. 
short Amplitude=0;//The possible value is 0 to 32767.
int ADCSampleRate=100;//Specifies sample rate of the ADC in Hz.
DWORD_PTR UserData = null;

G39DDC_CALLBACKS callbackStruct= new G39DDC_CALLBACKS();
lib.SetCallbacks(hDevice,callbackStruct,UserData);
     //hDevice is a handle for the hardware device used-- works in other uses
     //lib is a reference to the library in G39DDCAPI.java-- works in other uses
     //The UserData is a big unknown-- I don't know what to do with this variable
          //as a DWORD_PTR
callbackStruct.IFCallback.invoke(_Buffer, NumberOfSamples, CenterFrequency,
                                 Amplitude, ADCSampleRate,  UserData);
```

**EDIT NO 2:**

I have one callback working somewhat, but I don't have control over the buffers.  More frustratingly, a single call to invoke the method will result in several runs of the custom callback, usually with multiple output files (results vary drastically from run to run).  I don't know if it is because I am not allocating memory correctly on the Java side, because I cannot free the memory on the C/C++ side, or because I have no cue on which to tell Java to access the buffer, etc.  Relevant code looks like:

```
//before this, main method sets library, starts DDCs, initializes some variables...

//API call to start IF
System.out.print("Starting IF...             "+lib.StartIF(hDevice, Period)+"\n")
G39DDC_CALLBACKS  callbackStructure = new G39DDC_CALLBACKS();
callbackStructure.IFCallback = new G39DDC_IF_CALLBACK(){

    @Override 
    public void invoke(Pointer _Buffer,  int NumberOfSamples, int CenterFrequency,
            short Amplitude, int ADCSampleRate,   DWORD_PTR UserData  )  {

    //notification
        System.out.println("Invoked IFCallback!!");

        try {
    //ready file and writers
            File filePath = new File("/users/user/G39DDC_Scans/");
            if (!filePath.exists()){
                System.out.println("Making new directory...");
                filePath.mkdir();
            }

            String filename="Scan_"+System.currentTimeMillis();
            File fille= new File("/users/user/G39DDC_Scans/"+filename+".txt");
            if (!fille.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Making new file...");
                fille.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(fille.getAbsoluteFile());
    //callback body
            short[] deBuff=new short[NumberOfSamples];
            int offset=0;
            int arraySize=NumberOfSamples;

            deBuff=_Buffer.getShortArray(offset,arraySize); 
            for (int i=0; i<NumberOfSamples; i++){
                String str=deBuff[i]+",";
                fw.write(str);
            }
                fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("IOException: "+e1);
        }
    }
};

lib.SetCallbacks(hDevice, callbackStructure,UserData);
System.out.println("Main, before callback invocation");

callbackStructure.IFCallback.invoke(s_Pointer, NumberOfSamples, CenterFrequency, Amplitude, ADCSampleRate, UserData);
System.out.println("Main, after callback invocation");

//suddenly having trouble stopping DDCs or powering off device; assume it has to do with dll using the functions above
    //System.out.println("StopIF:   " + lib.StopIF(hDevice));//API function returns boolean value
    //System.out.println("StopDDC2: " + lib.StopDDC2( hDevice, Channel));
    //System.out.println("StopDDC1: " + lib.StopDDC1( hDevice, Channel ));
    //System.out.println("test_finishDevice: " + test_finishDevice( hDevice, lib));

System.out.println("Program Exit");

//END MAIN METHOD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to extend `StdCallCallback`, for one, otherwise you'll likely crash when the native code tries to call the Java code.

Any place you see a Windows type with `_PTR`, you should use a `PointerType` - the platform package with JNA includes definitions for `DWORD_PTR` and friends.

Finally, you can't have a primitive array argument in your `G39DDC_IF_CALLBACK`.  You'll need to use `Pointer` or an NIO buffer; `Pointer.getShortArray()` may then be used to extract the `short[]` by providing the desired length of the array.

**EDIT**

Yes, you need to initialize your callback field in the callbacks structure before passing it into your native function, otherwise you're just passing a NULL pointer, which will cause complaints on the Java or native side or both.

This is what it takes to create a callback, using an anonymous instance of the declared callback function interface:

```
myStruct.callbackField = new MyCallback() {
    public void invoke(int arg) {
        // do your stuff here
    }
};
```

Comment: I know the answer corrected one misconception I had; that StdCallCallback was only for interacting with the background Windows OS.  I think the suggestions will eventually answer my question, but I need to read up on NIO buffers before I can try any new code.  Thanks for now, and as soon as I get something working, I will check the answer as accepted.

Comment: I made several changes to the types, as seen above.  I KNOW my approach is totally wrong; the callback structure is supposed to provide access to a custom-defined callback such that somewhere along the line, there needs to be a place to provide a method body on the Java side-- part of my problem is I don't know where I can do this without making my compiler complain.

Comment: Using your feedback, I have been able to get the java side method execute a generic println statement, which indicates that I have the syntax working, so I am checking this as answered.  I'm still having some problems with managing the buffers, but that comes from my inexperience with them.  I'll post an update later if I can get them working.